# Error: "<Class> is not abstract and does not override abstract method <method>"

Tags: java, interface

Error :

> java:com.company.Bicycle is not abstract and does not override abstract method applyBreakes(int) in com.company.Vehicle and same for the Bike class.

```
package com.company;

interface Vehicle {

//all are the abstract method.
void changeGear(int a);
void speedUp(int a);
void applyBreakes(int a);
}



class Bicycle implements Vehicle {

int speed;
int gear;

//to change speed
@Override
public void changeGear(int newGear) {

    gear = newGear;

}

//to increase speed
@Override
public void speedUp(int increment) {

    speed = speed + increment;

}

//to decrease speed
public void applyBreaks(int decrement) {

    speed = speed - decrement;

}

public  void  printStates() {

    System.out.println("speed: " + speed + " gear: " + gear);
}

}

class Bike implements  Vehicle {

int speed;
int gear;

//to change gear
@Override
public void changeGear(int newGear) {

    gear = newGear;

}

//to increase speed
@Override
public void speedUp(int increment) {

    speed = speed + increment;

}

//to decrease speed
public void applyBreaks(int decrement) {

    speed = speed - decrement;

}

public void printStates() {

    System.out.println("speed: " + speed + " gear: " + gear);
}

}




class GFG {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //creating an instance of Bicycle
    //doing some operations
    Bicycle bicycle = new Bicycle();
    bicycle.changeGear(2);
    bicycle.speedUp(3);
    bicycle.applyBreaks(1);

    System.out.println("Bike present state :");
    bicycle.printStates();

    //creating instance of bike.
    Bike bike = new Bike();
    bike.changeGear(1);
    bike.speedUp(4);
    bike.applyBreaks(3);

    System.out.println("Bike present state :");
    bike.printStates();

}
}
```

Comment: Because you called it `applyBreakes` in the interface, not `applyBreaks`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you misspelled the method name in the interface (and/or in the implementation).

Interface method name is `applyBreakes`, while the implementations call it `applyBreaks`. 
So the classes don't implement the interface method, but instead define new (unrelated) methods.

---

P.S. The correct spelling (in English) would be "applyBrakes".

Comment: Thanks  @Alex Shesterov

Answer (score 1):

> "java:com.company.Bicycle is not abstract and does not override
>   abstract method applyBreakes(int) in com.company.Vehicle and same for
>   the Bike class."

Means that the Bicycle class has a number of methods, but not enough methods to be a fully defined class.

In this case, the missing method is the one that `Vehicle` says must be implemented, the `applyBreaks(int)` method.

Answer (score 0):

The method to implement in the interface is `applyBreakes()` but you implement `applyBreaks()` in the concrete class.
It seems to be a spelling error.

Fortunately, you can protect you against this kind of compilation error early if you annotate all your overriding/implementing methods with `@Override`.

You did it with for example :

```
@Override
public void speedUp(int increment) {
    speed = speed + increment;
}
```

but you didn't do it with :

```
public void applyBreaks(int decrement) {
    speed = speed - decrement;
}
```

Annotate it with `@Override` and the compilation error message would be more explicit :

```
@Override 
public void applyBreaks(int decrement) {
    speed = speed - decrement;
}
```